# GDB error: Selected architecture i386 is not compatible with reported target architecture i386:x86-64

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, gdb, netbeans-8

Does anyone know what this error means?

[image]

I'm working with Netbeans 8.0, gdb 7.8.1 on Linux Machine. Everything was good until two days ago, then I suddenly started to get this error when i'm starting t debug and I have no clue what it means.
So far, I'm trying to clean and reset everything I could think about: reinstall netbeans, clean all local files, rebase my code again, unset all breakpoints and so on and so on.
Could anyone please help me to understand what this error means? I've never set those breakpoints, where does Netbeans take themfrom?

Thanks in advance,
Rachel

**EDIT**

So now I have a bit more details:
When I'm trying to debug my app directly with GDB, without netbeans I'm getting the following error:

> Starting program: ....
>   warning: Selected architecture i386 is not compatible with reported target architecture i386:x86-64
>   warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description
>   Warning:
>   Cannot insert breakpoint -1.
>   Temporarily disabling shared library breakpoints:
>   breakpoint #-1
>   Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
>   Cannot access memory at address 0x8081527

how can I figure out what code\flag in compilation makes my app to be i386?  how can I force it to be x86_64?

Thanks again.

Comment: But,you were developing your code before that, correct?
And when exactly this message pops up?

Comment: There is NetBeans logfile. On my machine it's in `~/.netbeans/8.2/var/log`

Comment: Maybe you need to clean up breakpoints from previous session. See debugging/breakpoints window and remove any breakpoints.

Comment: I already did, but still having this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, the gdb installation on my machine was screwed. 
There's no chance anyone could imagine it. I moved to another machine and everything is good now.

Answer (score 4):

This error could appear when you try to use WSL gdb on non-WSL app.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me, getting this error on WSL. Runs without errors on native Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I think you updated the system and the latest version of the glib is not supporting 32bit applications.

Can you do a find to find out which files in all the `bin` and `lib` directories on your system were changed within the last 2 days?  If it used to support it, but the upgraded version doesn't, then the application which was (probably without your knowledge) compiled to be 32-bit will not be a valid target for all the standard tools on the box.

You specify the target architecture with `-m32` or `-m64`.  See if you can specify it explicitly if you are compiling and debugging on different machines.

Comment: I checked my app and all the shared libraries it uses - they are all x32. any other idea?